# What's the general terminology for the zero property of multiplication

Tags: terminology

In multiplication, `x • 1 = x`. We say that 1 is the identity element for multiplication. In addition, 0 is the identity element, because `x + 0 = x`. In conjunctions, true is the identity element, because `x and true = x`. In disjunctions, false is the identity element, because `x or false = x`.

Similarly, in multiplication, `x • 0 = 0`. We call this the zero property of multiplication, but what is the general term for it? I.e., what do I call it for conjunctions, where `x and false = false`, and disjunctions, where `x or true = true`?

Comment: Not sure if this is widespread - but I might suggest something along the lines of "absorbing element".  So, when $x \cdot 0 = 0$, the picture would be that 0 "absorbs" the $x$ term.

Comment: @DanielSchepler — Wikipedia thinks it's the correct term: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_element
Turn that into an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic term is [absorbing element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_element),
but in [semigroup theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup), this term is never used and such an element is called a *zero*.

More precisely, let $S$ be a semigroup. An element $z$ of $S$ such that $xz = z= zx$  for all $x \in S$ is called a *zero*. It is called a *left zero* if $z = zx$ for all $x \in S$ and a *right zero* if $z = xz$ for all $x \in S$.

If a semigroup has a zero, then this zero is unique (this is actually true for magmas). However, a semigroup may have several right zeros or several left zeros, but if a semigroup (or simply a magma) has a right zero and a left zero, then it has a zero.